# On my Blog - matching query does not exists

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have tried to learn like this. And try to develop my blog and add SLUG to the function But it is not possible to add new posts at all Do you have a solution or a way to make it work?

https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_forms/

on Models like this.

```
class Post(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField
author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
content_images = models.ImageField(default='Choose Your Images')
title = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)
content = models.TextField()
created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
post_viewcount = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, default='Enter SEO URL')
status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS , default=0)
```

and views.py like this

```
def create_post(request):
form = Createcontent
return render(request, 'blog/post_creator.html', {'form': form})
```

and urls.py like this

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
path('content/<slug:slug>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
path('content/createcontent/', views.create_post, name='create_post'),
```

and html file.

```html
   {% extends 'blog/base.html' %} {% block content %}
<h2>New post</h2>
<form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %} {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your `'create_post'` path, the `<slug:slug>` will first capture this, since `createcontent` is a valid slug as well. Therefore you should alter the `urlpatterns`. You can swap the two:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('content/createcontent/', views.create_post, name='create_post'),
    path('content/<slug:slug>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
]
```

so now `createcontent` will be matched first, but still this is *not* a good solution, since now if your article has as slug `createcontent`, you can not display it. Likely it is better to make *non-overlapping* paths. For example:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('content/createcontent/', views.create_post, name='create_post'),
    path('post/<slug:slug>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
]
```

here regardless what the value for `slug` is, it will never overlap with the `content/createcontent` path.

You of course still need to finish the view itself, since right now, it will not handle a POST request properly.